# Apps Script: How to add google search link to cell value on edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

My sheet contains 2 columns: A and B. Each cell in column A contains a company name. And each cell in column B contains the formula below to turn each value out of column A into a google search link, where the search term is the value coming from column A.

**Here is an example:** A3 has the value “Company Test AG”. So, the value in B3 after running the formula below in that very same cell B3 would be  https://www.google.de/search?q=Company%20Test%20AG

```
=hyperlink("www.google.de/search?q="&A3,A3)
```

**Question:** How can I implement this formula in Apps Script **and** ensure that it triggers only when the user explicitly writes in column B of the current cell he´s working on i.e. “*company details needed*”, “*company details missing*” or something similar?

Thank you so much in advance for your help and hints :)

Comment: @Cooper - Any idea or suggestion how to deal with this? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Bob, I posted an answer, let me know if that works for you. I'm not sure whether you want to check whether users write `company details needed` or `company details missing` on the cell, or maybe you don't want that and I misunderstood. If that's the case, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

If I understand you correctly, you want the cell in column `B` to be updated with the hyperlink whenever that same cell is edited with the sentences `company details needed` or `company details missing`.

If this is the case, you can do this:

- Use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to execute this on user edits.
- Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to check that the appropriate cell and values are written.
- Use [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value) to build the hyperlink.
- Use [setRichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue) to set that hyperlink.

#### Code sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addHyperlink(e);
  // Other functions called by onEdit
}

function addHyperlink(e) {
  const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet2"; // Change according to your preferences
  const TEXT_COL_INDEX = 1; // Where text for hyperlink will be written
  const TRIGGER_COL_INDEX = 2; // Text that triggers script (company details, etc.)
  const TARGET_COL_INDEX = 3; // Hyperlink column
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const sentences = ["company details needed", "company details missing"].map(s => s.toUpperCase());
  if (range.getColumn() === TRIGGER_COL_INDEX && sheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME && sentences.includes(e.value.toUpperCase())) {
    const row = range.getRow();
    const value = sheet.getRange(row, TEXT_COL_INDEX).getValue(); // Get value in column A
    const link = "www.google.de/search?q=" + value;
    const richTextValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
                                        .setText(value)
                                        .setLinkUrl(link)
                                        .build();
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), TARGET_COL_INDEX).setRichTextValue(richTextValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: First off, thank you so much for reacting. I have 4 issues with your solution: A) it makes changes to ALL sheets instead of just to 1 specific sheet (I have 4 sheets in my google spreadsheet), B) it is case sensitive, C) I cannot decide if I want the result to be in another column than column B, and D) I already have many other functions that run onEdit. So, is there any possibility to make your code a little bit more flexible? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @BobHardball I updated my answer based on your comments. I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much again. The only issue remaining is with `const COL_INDEX`. Anytime I change the value of this constant to something else (i.e. `const COL_INDEX = 3`), nothing appears in that column where I am expecting to see the result. But I am 100% sure that the column I choose and declare as value of `const COL_INDEX` is 100% empty. Any suggestion?

Comment: @BobHardball Wait, the column in which values are written by the user and the column where hyperlinks are populated might not be the same? Up to this point I assume they were the same. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @BobHardball I updated my answer again so that the column where user enters data is always B but the target column can get changed via `COL_INDEX`. Apologies for my previous misunderstanding.

Comment: One last important question: B is where the user writes something, and this user input is perfectly captured down in your code with `range.getColumn() === 2`. But is it possible to re-organize your script, so that instead of column B I can choose another column for this user input? Because with your code that works perfectly fine, the user MUST always enter the value in column B. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: @BobHardball I updated my answer again so that you can set (1) column for text to look for in hyperlink, (2) column to trigger the script, (3) column with hyperlink

Comment: Thank you so much. But in the end, I worked a little bit on the previous version. I mean I changed the offset value for `const value = range.offset(0,-1)` to determine where I wanted to the hyperlink to appear. Thank you so much!!! I really, really, really appreciate!!!!